# Квадратики в Java метод setLength()

Tags: java, строки

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("Тест");
        stringBuffer.setLength(10);
        System.out.println(stringBuffer);
    }
}
```

Метод - устанавливает длину строки. Но вот такой результат я получаю если у меня указано в методе значение больше чем в самом конструкторе. Что за квадратики? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

А что вы ожидали?
Длина вашей строки - 4, вы хотите её сделать 10. Строка дополняется нулевыми символами (`\u0000`), они у вас и выводятся.

[документация](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#setLength(int))